# pegar valor de uma function e colocar em uma variavel

Tags: php, javascript

Pessoal como posso passar os atributos abaixo em uma variável?

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#btnInfoMaq", function () {
    var info = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var str = info.split('|');
    var serie_maquina = str[0];
    var grupo_maquina = str[1];
    $(".modal-body #serie_maquina").val(serie_maquina);
    $(".modal-body #grupo_maquina").val(grupo_maquina);
});
```

---

Então... no script acima eu pego os dados através de um botão!

```
<?php echo "<button class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalInfoMaq' id='btnInfoMaq' data-id='$serie_maquina|$grupo_maquina'> Informação</button>"?>
```

passo elas para um modal, com o codigo acima... o problema e que no modal, so consigo recuperar as informaçoes dentro de um input hidel... mas oque eu queria era pegar estas informaçoes dentro de uma variavel do php! para conseguir realizar uma consulta.

como posso pegar essas informaçoes e coloca-las em uma variavel $?

Comment: Esclareça um pouco mais de detalhes sobre o que você quer realmente. Você marcou a tag php mas não escreveu nada sobre.

Comment: esclareci abaixo!

Comment: Para incluir novas informações na pergunta, por favor use o link de [edit] acima. Não use a área de respostas abaixo.

Comment: como eu poderia resolver esta questão? ja tentei usar <script>document.write(serie_maquina)</script> mas sem sucesso...

Comment: Você quer adicionar um determinado valor em uma variável do PHP via JavaScript?

Comment: Isso... quero pegar aquelas duas variáveis que estão ali no java script... serie_maquina e grupo_maquina e colocar o valor delas em uma variável php.

Comment: O PHP já terminou de rodar quando o JavaScript executa. Se precisa mesmo passar um valor para o PHP (para salvar ou consultar algo no banco de dados, por exemplo), vai precisar usar Ajax.

Comment: e como posso fazer isso ? exemplo!

Comment: Tem como eu passar os atributos por post para o modal?

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer, não está muito claro. Poderia [edit] e complementar a pergunta?

Comment: Mas o que realmente aconteceu quando você clica no botão #btnInfoMaq ? A dificuldade em responder-lhe é devido ao fato de não ser possível reconstituir o problema. Por favor reelabore a questão ou a edite acrescentando mais detalhes como sugerido pelo colega. Fato é que a ordem de execuçºao do código PHP e do Javascript pode afetar o resultado esperado.